# How to fetch different from two uncommited git branch

Tags: git

I have one git branch dev and this branch contain uncommit changes.
Without committing changes to dev branch, we have created new branch from dev like dev1.

Now, some work done in dev1. How to fetch only dev1 branch changes?

Comment: "fetch" means to get/retrieve/bring. You seem to use it as "to send/push/merge"...(can't say exactly)? Your last sentence doesn't make much sense as is.

Comment: *i want to fetch only dev1 branch changes*: `git checkout dev1`

Comment: i want to get only branch dev1 change like 
git diif 
display all differences.
this way i want to get changes.

Comment: Not much clearer, I'm sorry. to get changes? You already have them, noobody else has since you created the branch yourself. So it makes no sense to want to get them. There's clearly a miscommunication somewhere.

Comment: Uncommitted changes aren't "on" a branch.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I didn't want to go down this *other* rabbit hole but you're right ^^ I assumed he meant "that branch was checked out with these uncommited changes on top."

Comment: Hm.. I am also a bit confused by this question - I don't understand what you're asking. I assume English is your second language. Could you write a question in a language you are more proficient in and run it through a translator - maybe that could help us understand better.

Comment: step 1. dev branch contain some which is not commit.
step 2. create new branch from dev.
step 3. start some work with new branch.
now i want get only those changes which is in new branch.
*only new branch changes i want not in dev.

Answer (score 0):

From the question asked, I believe bhumika may not have a complete understanding of how git works. I will attempt to answer the question I think he is asking.

> I have one git branch dev and this branch contain uncommit changes.

```
 git checkout dev
 <create and edit *file1*, do not commit>
```

> Without committing changes to dev branch, we have created new branch
>   from dev like dev1

```
git checkout -b dev1
```

> Now, some work done in dev1.

```
<create and edit *file2* and *file3*>
```

> How to fetch only dev1 branch changes?

Note that uncommitted changes are NOT on any branch. Git has no way of knowing you want only file2 and file3 committed on dev1, and file1 on dev.

You need to tell git what you want:

```
<you are on branch dev1>
git add file2 file3
git commit <add file2, file3 to commit on dev1>

git checkout dev
git add file1
git commit <add file1 to commit on dev>
```

Comment: Note that if you are working on multiple branches at once, you will want to commit your changes before switching to a second branch. If you don't, you will bring your worktree changes with you when you switch branches, and Git has no way to know which intended changes go with which branch unless they are committed.